# addEventListener gets executed on the second click

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, typescript

The `window.addEventListener` is getting `executed` only on the `second click` and surprisingly, after I click once on the `li element` to read the task and again clicking on delete button, then the read task event gets fired up! as I'm keeping the `delete button` mapped inside the `list element`.

list element has a click handler to `read the task information`.

The delete button has its `remove task handler`. I'm attaching the events to `stop event propagation` to its parent.

**On delete button click only `removeTask` method should get executed and on read task information only the `readTheTask` method should get called.**

The `first problem` here is, as I'm using the addEventListener, it only gets executed after the second click.

And the `second problem` if I remove attaching the eventListeners then on delete button click, the read task event also gets fired up!

How to resolve these issues?? Expecting some genuine solutions. The help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the => [**Working Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-task-demo-mjdwp3)

Here's my code:

```
window.deleteTask = function deleteTask(id) {
 const deleteButton = document.getElementById(id);
  deleteButton.addEventListener(
    "click",
    (event) => {
      // event.preventDefault();
      let taskAppObj = new ToDoConstructor();
      taskAppObj.removetask(id);
      event.stopPropagation();
    },
    false
  );
};

window.getTaskInfo = function getTaskInfo(id) {
  const li = document.getElementById(`data-${id}`);
  li.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    let taskAppObj = new ToDoConstructor();
    let task = window.storeContext.find((task) => task.id === id);
    taskAppObj.readTheTask(task);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using `createElement` instead string literal and you do not pass an initial argument on any *Event listener function* it always be a event argument, it is a good practice.

```
function getTaskList() {
  let tasks = [...window.storeContext];
  console.log("tasl", tasks);
  const taskListUl = document.getElementById("task-elements");
  taskListUl.innerHTML =
    tasks && tasks.length > 0
      ? tasks
          .map(
            (task) =>
              `<li  id=data-${task.id} onclick="getTaskInfo(event)" key=${task.id}>
                ${task.title}
                <button id=${task.id} onclick="deleteTask(event)">X</button>
              </li>`
          )
          .join("<br/>")
      : null;
}
```

ReadTask

```
window.getTaskInfo = function getTaskInfo(event) {
  const id = event.currentTarget.id.split('-')[1];
  let taskAppObj = new ToDoConstructor();
  let task = window.storeContext.find((task) => task.id === Number(id));
  taskAppObj.readTheTask(task);
};
```

Delete Task

```
window.deleteTask = function deleteTask(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  const id = event.currentTarget.id;
  console.log("I am delte function!");
  let taskAppObj = new ToDoConstructor();
  taskAppObj.removetask(Number(id));
}
```

Also tested in the codesandbox

Comment: Ok. This is a solution by completely changing the way I was going forward. But not a genuine solution for the problem which I was looking for. So do you have any solution going forward with my approach of getting the list of tasks using the template literals??

Comment: I have changed the code based on template literals @Subhojit

Comment: Thank you yuvaraj. Can you change the **event.target.id** in the code to **event.currentTarget.id**??

Comment: I have changed and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  init();
}, 1000);

const ToDoConstructor = function () {
  this.toDoList = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Task 1",
      description: "Meditation",
      priority: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Task 2",
      description: "Room Cleaning",
      priority: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Task 3",
      description: "Washing Clothes",
      priority: 3
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "Task 4",
      description: "Studying",
      priority: 4
    }
  ];
  this.readTheTask = function (params) {
    const taskDisplayDiv = document.getElementById("task-info");
    const titleSpan = document.getElementById("titleSpan");
    const descrSpan = document.getElementById("descrSpan");
    const prioritySpan = document.getElementById("prioritySpan");

    taskDisplayDiv.setAttribute("class", "visible");

    titleSpan.innerHTML = params.title;
    descrSpan.innerHTML = params.description;
    prioritySpan.innerHTML = params.priority;
  };
  this.removetask = function (id) {
    // This function accepts id of a task to be removed from toDoList
    if (window.storeContext.length > 0) {
      this.toDoList = [...window.storeContext];
    }

    

    this.toDoList = this.toDoList.filter((element) => element.id !== id);

    window.storeContext = [...this.toDoList];

   

    getTaskList();
  };
};

function init() {
  const taskAppObj = new ToDoConstructor();
  window.storeContext = [...taskAppObj.toDoList];
  getTaskList();
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const taskListUl = document.getElementById("task-elements");

  taskListUl.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
      const id = event.target.id;
      deleteTask(id);
    } else if (event.target.tagName === "LI") {
      const id = event.target.id.split("-")[1]; // Extract the ID from the element's ID
      getTaskInfo(id);
    }
  });
});

function deleteTask(id) {
  let taskAppObj = new ToDoConstructor();
  taskAppObj.removetask(id);
}

function getTaskInfo(id) {
  let taskAppObj = new ToDoConstructor();
  let task = window.storeContext.find((task) => task.id == id);
  taskAppObj.readTheTask(task);
}

function getTaskList() {
  let tasks = [...window.storeContext];
  console.log("tasks", tasks);
  const taskListUl = document.getElementById("task-elements");
  taskListUl.innerHTML = "";

  if (tasks && tasks.length > 0) {
    tasks.forEach((task) => {
      const listItem = document.createElement("li");
      listItem.id = `data-${task.id}`;

      const taskTitle = document.createElement("span");
      taskTitle.innerText = task.title;

      const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
      deleteButton.innerText = "x";

      // Attach a click event listener to the list item
      listItem.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
     
        if (event.target.tagName === "SPAN") {
          getTaskInfo(task.id);
        }
      });

      // Attach a click event listener to the Delete button
      deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent the click event on the list item from firing
        deleteTask(task.id);
      });

      listItem.appendChild(taskTitle);
      listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
      taskListUl.appendChild(listItem);
    });
  }
}

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<h1>Tasks</h1>
<div class=task-display-div>
  <div class=task-col>
    <header>Task List</header>
    <div>
      <ul id=task-elements>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=task-col>
    <header>
      Task Details:
    </header>
    <div id=task-info class=hidden>
      <div>
        <h5>Task Title: </h5><SPAN id=titleSpan></SPAN>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Task Details: </h5><SPAN id=descrSpan></SPAN>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>It is a prio <SPAN id=prioritySpan></SPAN> task.</h5>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.task-display-div {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
}

.task-col {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

By doing some changes in your code it is working in single click (check result on full page)